# SQA Software Quality Assurance / CMMI-DEV model

Tags: cmmi

I am studying ***Software Quality Assurance book by Alian and Claude***, when I finished reading chapter 4 about CMMI, I found this question in the exercise section in the end of the chapter, **Can the CMMI-DEV model be used for development in an organization with 10 developers? Explain why or why not.**

I've read that the **CMMI** is flexible model so an organization with 10 developers can use the model.
but also I've read that one of disadvantages of **CMMI-DEV** is may not be suitable for every organization.

I've get confused is it really a flexible model and a 10 developers can use it?